# Can I backup VMware Workstation settings (e.g. favorites, etc.) so that I can import them into another VMware Workstation install?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have VMware Workstation installed on Server 2008. I am backing up Virtual Machines so that I can restore them later. Is there any way to backup VMware Workstation's settings as well so that I don't have to manually open VMs and add them to favorites or change settings for things like adapters?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like most, if not all, settings for Workstation are stored in the registry if on Windows. Here is a communities articles containing a script and some information to dump the settings into registry files: http://communities.vmware.com/message/157381

Note: The vmxnet registry keys appear to be unique per install. You'd probably need some more fancy scripting to loop through keys to find the proper vmxnet entries and dump them to be truly portable.